# How do I get the apk file of my kivy app using mapview to work. Nothing is working

Tags: ubuntu, mobile, kivy, apk, buildozer

Even with a very simple kivy mapview app. I cant get the apk file for my app to work and it keeps crashing at launch. Can anyone help me get the apk file for this very simple app with the following code.
This is the main.py file code:

```
from kivy.app import App

class MainApp(App):
    pass

MainApp().run()
```

This is my main.kv file code:

```
#:import MapView kivy_garden.mapview.MapView

MapView:
```

Comment: Capture the `logcat` from your android device and see if there is a hint there. See the [documentation](https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#run-my-application).

Comment: Hey thanks it worked but now I am facing a new problem in my ubuntu buildozer file. Let me know if you are familiar with this or if anyone is familiar with this error
Valueerror: MDRaisedButton._md_bg_color has an invalid format (got [0.12941176470588237, 0.5882352941176471, 0.9529411764705882, 1]) in my ubuntu buildozer

Comment: @JohnAnderson These are my requirements in my buildozer.spec file python==8.0.26,mysql==0.0.3,PIL==8.3.1,kivymd==0.104.2,kivy==2.0.0rc1,requests,certifi,urllib3,chardet,idna,plyer,kivy_garden.mapview,pytz